# Count Items in Access 2003

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2003

I have a table which contains a column with different items which i would like to count by there type. For example the table looks like the following:

```
Id |  Type
---|----
1  | Table
2  | Table
3  | TV
4  | TV
5  | Table
6  | TV
7  | TV
```

The result should looks like:

```
Type  | NumOfItems
------|----------
Table | 3
TV    | 4
```

I use the following code which doesn't work for my Access 2003:

```
SELECT Table1.Type, Count(Table1.Type) AS NumOfItems
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add  GROUP BY Table1.Type to the end of the query.

Comment: Thanks! this has helped! Maybe you also know how to add the TOTAL line in the output table? Would be very thankful.